# is there a constructor when using document.register

Tags: javascript, html

I'm experimenting with document.register, with which I create a custom element as follows:

```
var XFoo = document.register('x-foo', {
    prototype: Object.create(HTMLElement.prototype, {
      bar: {
        get: function() { return 5; }
      },
      foo: {
        value: function() {
          alert('foo() called');
        }
      }
    })
  });
```

Now I was wondering if it is possible to define a constructor function which is called when a x-foo element is created ?

In  my case I want to add some child elements and some classes, so if you define something like

```
<x-foo></x-foo>
```

I want to add a div

```
<x-foo class="bar foo">
  <div class="x-foo__child"/>
</x-foo>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [lifecycle callback methods](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webcomponents/customelements/#lifecycle):

```
var XFooProto = Object.create(HTMLElement.prototype);
XFooProto.createdCallback = function() {
  //do instantiation stuff

  this.classList.add('foo');
  this.classList.add('bar');

  var child = document.createElement('div');
  child.classList.add('x-foo__child');
  this.appendChild(child);

  // for testing
  child.textContent = 'hello';
};

var XFoo = document.register('x-foo', { prototype: XFooProto });
```

[**Demo**](http://jsbin.com/ejivObO/2/edit)

I've removed the extra defined properties in the prototype object to make the answer shorter as those are unrelated to the presented question, feel free to add them again as the second argument to `Object.create`.

You can remove the `var XFoo =` part if you don't intend to use it as a constructor (`new XFoo()`) in your code as well. You can also use `document.createElement('x-foo')` for the same result in case you'd like to programmatically create new XFoos.